# shell_exec pass $_GET variable to EXE

Tags: php, exe

I'm trying to take info from $_GET and pass it along to an exe file that needs 1 argument supplied to it, and used the input from $_GET to be that argument but it's executing the .exe and NOT passing the variable, it then hangs the .exe till I end process.

index form for sending:

```
<form action="/test.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="input" />

<input type="submit" value=" OK " />
```

the php script that it sends to.

```
  <html>
<head><title>PHP Get Send</title></head>

<body>

<?php
$var = $_GET['input'];

$x = shell_exec("test.exe ".$var);

echo $x;
?>


</body>

</html>
```

I can't figure this out, at all. It just refuses to properly execute the exe with the variable sent. I can do it from command prompt, etc, a bat file, but soon as i try and do it from PHP it hangs the exe and doesn't send the variable.

Comment: does `shell_exec( "test.exe param1 param2" )` (or whatever params you need) work ? What kind of exe is that ? Does it expect input from stdin ?  Is it GUI ? Besides that: be very careful with that approach. What happens if someone calls your php with "...& format C: /u" ?

Comment: This is why exec is dangerous, because you're giving command line access to your server to ANYONE who sends a get variable to that page. Please put some validation on `$var` to limit it to the acceptable parameters to pass `test.exe`.

Comment: I can deal with sanitation later, for now it won't even send the variable. Sanitation can be added easily after I get it actually working. And as far as the exe it's executing goes, it's just a simple AHK exe that takes the param1 and switches to a seperate window and types what param1 is.

Comment: This is exec() so sanitation isn't enough, I'd suggest only giving the user who fill up the "input" limited selections and checking using switch() whether the sent input matches one of the approved input values, otherwise, you are vulnerable.

Comment: Again, right now it doesn't even work and no one is attempting to help with that. You're all just farming karma points by saying "sanitation pls"